# How to create authorization checking with Tcode

Tags: authorization, abap

How to create authorization checking with tcode? I have tried many ways like creating transaction ZSDI_DRIVER_INFO and ZSDR_DRIVER_INFO during in tcode se80 and assigned the authorization object (F_BKPF_BUK) to the respective tcode.

But nothing change, even when testing I try to insert data not in authorization, It still allows the user to save. I am new in SAP ABAP. Hopefully can get some advice on this...

I create Transaction code here:

[image]

and add f_bkpf_buk at tcode su24
[image]

I think is putting here but not sure how...try many ways ady:

```
MODULE USER_COMMAND_0100 INPUT.


  CASE ok_code.
    WHEN 'CONFIRM' .

      CALL TRANSACTION 'ZSDI_DRIVER_INFO'.

      IF gv_bukrs IS INITIAL
        OR gv_icno IS INITIAL
        OR gv_status IS INITIAL.

        MESSAGE 'Please fill in field required.' type 'E'.
        CALL SCREEN '0100'.

      ENDIF.
      PERFORM check_data.
    WHEN 'QUERY'.
      CALL SCREEN '0200'.
    WHEN 'UPDATE'.
      IF gv_bukrs IS INITIAL
        OR gv_icno IS INITIAL
        OR gv_status IS INITIAL.

        MESSAGE 'Please fill in field required.' type 'E'.
        CALL SCREEN '0100'.
      ENDIF.
      PERFORM check_data2.

    WHEN 'EXIT'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
  ENDCASE.

ENDMODULE.
```

The requirement as stated below:
[image]

Most of the tutorial online teach how to create normal authorization object that without tcode, hopefully can get some help about how to create this authorization checking.

Comment: Why do you seem searching desperately for authorization check "with transaction code"? An authorization check is to be done in ABAP, whatever the context is = [`AUTHORITY-CHECK`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapauthority-check.htm).

Comment: Are the programs behind the transaction code `ZSDI_DRIVER_INFO` and `ZSDR_DRIVER_INFO` programs you control or are they SAP standard programs?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with tcode, assigning the auth to tcode is the last step of your solution. You need value-based authorizations. Learn the basics https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-us/52/6712ac439b11d1896f0000e8322d00/content.htm?no_cache=true